# How do I use after_save_callback_chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

The main documentation describe it at debugging callbacks but it seems to not exists:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

I've tried to use just like the example and it returns me:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :026 > Device.after_save_callback_chain
NoMethodError: undefined method `after_save_callback_chain' for #<Class:0x104bc1060>
    from /rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this method has disappeared in Rails 3. I've used the following before :

```
Model._save_callbacks.select { |callback| callback.kind.eql?(:after) }
```

This will get you any after_save callbacks. You can then get further information like the proc that's being called by checking the .filter attribute :

```
Model._save_callbacks.select { |callback| callback.kind.eql?(:after) }.collect(&:filter)
```

Hopefully someone has a nicer answer than this though.

This `_#{kind}_callbacks` method is defined on ActiveSupport I think so you can do similar stuff with controllers and whatnot I'd assume.

Comment: Good stuff, was going crazy trying to find out the callback order. This helped a lot.